# Returning NaN when multiplying a parsefloat string with an oncalculate input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('f5').value;   
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('f6').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('f8'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);

}
```

F6 is defined as:

```
<p oninput="calculate()" id="f6" class="change change-btc-usd-cmc input-group-addon"><i>Indlæser</i></p>
```

With the following jquery backend:

```
   $.getJSON( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/", function( data ) {
     $.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD", function (data2) {
  change['btc-usd-cmc'] = data[0]["price_usd"] * data2.rates["DKK"];
  $(".change-btc-usd-cmc").text(change['btc-usd-cmc']);
  $(".change-btc-usd-cmc").text(parseFloat(change['btc-usd-cmc']).toFixed(2));
  loader(false)
  updateData()          

})
```

f5 is simply defined as in html:

```
<input oninput="calculate()" type="text" class="form-control " id="f5" name="f5" value=""   placeholder="eks. 5000" 
data-rule-number="true" 
data-rule-min="999"  
data-rule-max="50000"  
data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Dette felt er krævet. "   />
```

change is defined as:

```
    var change = {
    "usd-vef-dt": null,
    "btc-usd-cmc": null,
    "rai-usd-cmc": null,
    "eth-usd-cmc": null,
"btc-vef-lbtc": null,
"usd-vef-lbtc": null,


}
```

I can't see why it returns NaN, they both end as numbers, so it shouldn't be a problem as parsefloat is used with the jQuery backend, yet it returns NaN. When two oncalculate text input is written instead, it works flawlessly.

Comment: what is `change` variable and where it's defined?

Comment: Added it in an edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uhm, `f6` is a `p` element, which has no value.. So, for `f6` value is `undefined`, and `undefined * 1 === NaN`

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/q58zpuch/

Comment: Changing it to <label> also adding type="number" does not make a difference. The error is somewhere else..

Comment: Only form elements have a `value` property (`input`, `textarea`, `select`, ...). So `label` will result in the same mess

Comment: Genius, I have been staring at it for so long that I didn't realise this.. This fixed it, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parseInt(variable)` to parse textbox value or textarea value in interger or `parseFloat(variable)` to parse value in float

`var myBox1 = document.getElementById('f5');                                                   var myBox2 = document.getElementById('f6');                                                     var result = document.getElementById('f8');                                                     var myResult = parseFloat(myBox1.value) * parseFloat(myBox2.value);`

try this it worked for me .